# Is it possible to add a data attribute to a DevDemon Forms form tag?

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-forms

I discovered that you can use attr:id and attr:class in a DevDemon Forms tag using parameters such as `attr:class="form-class"`. I didn't see this listed in the docs anywhere and now I'm wondering if it's possible to add a data attribute to the form tag as well?

Does anyone know if this is possible? I'd like to use some form validation that requires a data attribute on form tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we can not do this in forms. You could do it with Javascript though, since you have the ID. Just call some javascript afterwards and add the data attributes. I know it is a pain, but it would work for now.

Comment: Thanks Brad - that's what I was planning to do in the meantime, just figured it was worth asking since I didn't see the attr:class or attr:id in the docs but found that those worked fine. Thanks for getting back to me.